# RecyclerView Delete on swipe deletes element but not the hole in the list stays

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-diffutils

I'm working on simple notes app and struggling with recyclerview and note deletion. I use `DiffUtil` and the problem is when I delete the note, it disappears, but the rest of the elements do not pull up, taking up an empty space. It happens only if activity restarded (for example, by changing display orientation).

I've read there are bunch of `adapter.notify...` methods, but If I use `.notifyDataSetChanged()` or `.notifyItemRemoved(position)` I get strange behaviour: the note data deletes, but list item reappears almost immediately after been swiped and deleted

**Adapter**

```
class NoteAdapter @Inject constructor() : RecyclerView.Adapter<NoteAdapter.NotesViewHolder>() {

    private val differCallback = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<NoteEntity>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: NoteEntity, newItem: NoteEntity): Boolean {
            return oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }

        @SuppressLint("DiffUtilEquals")
        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: NoteEntity, newItem: NoteEntity): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }
    }

    val differ = AsyncListDiffer(this, differCallback)
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NotesViewHolder {

        val binding =
            ItemNoteBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return NotesViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return differ.currentList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NotesViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = differ.currentList[position]
        holder.binding.apply {

            tvTitle.text = item.noteTitle
            tvDesc.text = item.noteDescription

            // on item click
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
                onItemClickListener?.let { it(item) }
            }
        }
    }

    inner class NotesViewHolder(val binding: ItemNoteBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

    // on item click listener
    private var onItemClickListener: ((NoteEntity) -> Unit)? = null
    fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: (NoteEntity) -> Unit) {
        onItemClickListener = listener
    }
}
```

**MainFragmet**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_main) {

    private val viewModel: NoteViewModel by activityViewModels()
    lateinit var binding: FragmentMainBinding

    @Inject
    lateinit var noteRepo: NoteRepo

    @Inject
    lateinit var noteAdapter: NoteAdapter

    @Inject
    lateinit var note: NoteEntity

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        binding = FragmentMainBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        // SHOW AVAILABLE NOTES USING RV
        collectNotes()
        initSwipeToDeleteNote()
        onClickNote()

        // GO TO CREATE NEW NOTE BY PRESSING NEW NOTE BUTTON
        val button: FloatingActionButton = view.findViewById(R.id.btnAddNote)
        button.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(
                R.id.action_mainFragment_to_addNoteFragment
            )
        }
    }

    private fun onClickNote() {
        // onclick navigate to add notes
        noteAdapter.setOnItemClickListener {
            val bundle = Bundle().apply {
                putSerializable("note", it)
            }
            findNavController().navigate(
                R.id.action_mainFragment_to_updateNoteFragment,
                bundle
            )
        }
    }

    private fun collectNotes() {
        binding.apply {
            if (noteRepo.getAllNotes().isNotEmpty()) {
                rvNoteList.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                tvEmptyText.visibility = View.GONE
                noteAdapter.differ.submitList(noteRepo.getAllNotes())
                setupRecyclerView()
            } else {
                rvNoteList.visibility = View.GONE
                tvEmptyText.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
        }
    }

    private fun setupRecyclerView() = binding.rvNoteList.apply {
        adapter = noteAdapter
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
    }

    private fun initSwipeToDeleteNote() {
        // init item touch callback for swipe action
        val itemTouchHelperCallback = object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(
            ItemTouchHelper.UP or ItemTouchHelper.DOWN,
            ItemTouchHelper.LEFT or ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT
        ) {
            override fun onMove(
                recyclerView: RecyclerView,
                viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
                target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
            ): Boolean {
                return true
            }

            override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
                // get item position & delete notes
                val position = viewHolder.adapterPosition
                val note = noteAdapter.differ.currentList[position]
                viewModel.deleteNoteByID(
                    note.id
                )

                Snackbar.make(
                    binding.root,
                    getString(R.string.note_deleted_msg),
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG
                )
                    .apply {
                        setAction(getString(R.string.undo)) {
                            viewModel.addNote(
                                note.noteTitle!!,
                                note.noteDescription!!
                            )
                        }
                        show()
                    }
            }
        }

        // attach swipe callback to rv
        ItemTouchHelper(itemTouchHelperCallback).apply {
            attachToRecyclerView(binding.rvNoteList)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: 89]